# What's a cross platform way to play a sound file in python?

Tags: python, cross-platform, audio

I tried playing a .wav file using pyaudio. It works great on windows, but doesn't work in Ubuntu when another device is using sound.

> The error is "IOError: [Errorno
>   Invalid output device (no default
>   output device)] -9996

Is there another library I could try to use? Another method?

Answer (score 13):

You can use [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/)

```
sound = wx.Sound('sound.wav')
sound.Play(wx.SOUND_SYNC)
```

or

```
sound.Play(wx.SOUND_ASYNC)
```

[Here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/demo/Sound.py) is an example from the wxPython demo.

Comment: The demo link is broken

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at pymedia? It looks as easy as this to play a WAV file:

```
import time, wave, pymedia.audio.sound as sound
f= wave.open('YOUR FILE NAME', 'rb')
sampleRate= f.getframerate()
channels= f.getnchannels()
format= sound.AFMT_S16_LE
snd= sound.Output(sampleRate, channels, format)
s= f.readframes(300000)
snd.play(s)
while snd.isPlaying(): time.sleep(0.05)
```

Ref: http://pymedia.org/tut/play_wav.html

Of course, you can have a look at the Python wiki under Audio (http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/) for other libraries such as https://docs.python.org/library/wave.html or again in Python's wiki under Game Libraries (http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGameLibraries) that will point you to bindings to OpenAL or Pygame that has sound modules.

And finally, although I don't know the limitations of pyaudio, your error message sounds more like the library is not able to find the default output device more than the device is in use by another process. Maybe have a look at what output device is returned by the `get_default_output_device_info` of pyaudio and compare it to whatever's your default setting in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Simpleaudio](http://simpleaudio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
> pip install simpleaudio
```

Then:

```
import simpleaudio as sa

wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("path/to/file.wav")
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely sure if that fulfills your requirements, but I immediately thought PyGame

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
s = mixer.Sound('sound.wav')
s.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [`playsound`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/playsound) to be the simplest.

```
from playsound import playsound

is_synchronus = False
playsound(r"C:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav", is_synchronus)
```

Comment: Something happened to playaudio in recent releases: It no longer accepts the backslash character in file paths, so its portability is lost. You need to use the forward slash.

Comment: Couldn't you use `os.path.join` to allow Python to automatically use the correct slash? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#join