# Can eclipse notify me when a task has finished running?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am often stuck twiddling my thumbs for a couple minutes while eclipse cleans, builds, or loads my projects.  It would be nice if eclipse could notify me with a beep when the last task in the Progress view has finished running, so I can stop reading the internet and get back to work.  Is there a setting or plugin that does this?

**Edit:** I tried adapting the plugin template that nonty provided below, which adds a listener to the `JobManager`.  I tried implementing `done()` to beep only when the job change event's name contains "Building workspace," as that is the task that usually takes the longest in my setup.  Exasperatingly, the task that builds the workspace never sends a `done()` call, just `scheduled()` and `aboutToRun()` calls.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 13):

There are no preference for this - yet.

The `JobManager` have the needed API to support this functionality...

**EDIT**: I have constructed and attached a very simple plug-in that will beep for every job that terminates. That turns out to be rather often :-) . You can modify it to filter out all the false positives, e.g. by  `getPriority()` and `getName()`. Also you can make the listener play a tune, popup a message (don't!) or whatever...

See [jobnotifier.zip](http://goo.gl/ENCP2R?gdriveurl).

**UPDATED** the link above again

Comment: Thanks for making this plugin!  I'm having some trouble getting it to run, though.  I unzipped the folder, dropped it into my plugins directory, and restarted eclipse.  The plugin shows up under Help->About->Plugins, but I don't hear any beeps. :( (Eclipse 3.5.2)

Comment: Hmm... In the Console view, try to select the "Host OSGi Console". Then issue the commands `ss` ("short status") - this will list the plug-ins of the Eclipse installation along with their state. Check the jobnotifier plugin - likely the last. It should be state `STARTED`but can be `RESOLVED`- in the later case you can start it with the command `start _id_`...

Comment: @nonty The plugin's state was `RESOLVED`.  When I tried to start it, I got this stack trace: http://pastebin.com/Xiqj2kQr (Thanks so much for your help, by the way!)

Comment: Ahh... You wrote "I unzipped the folder, dropped it into my plugins directory, and restarted eclipse." If that is really the case, then it explains it :-) The zip contained the source code for you to modify - it did not contain the compiled ready-to-use bundle. Sorry for the confusion. You must first import the zip as a new project ("Existing Projects into WS"), then export it... and now you can put it into the `dropins` folder. Though I would recommend creating a feature and a update site as well..

Comment: Gotcha!  Thanks, got it working now.  You're right, it does beep a lot. :o)

Comment: This is a really good idea, and it really should work, but it turns out that eclipse sends the most ridiculous hodgepodge of `done()` calls, most of them useless.  See edit to my question.

Comment: It is vacation time, so a new version depends on the weather... So I don't hope you will get it the next couple of weeks..

Comment: This link isn't working for me. Not sure if it's just me. Please fix if possible. Thanks.