# Python library that directly produces sound

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I want to write a program in Python which plays random music. Is there any library that can directly play a sound of the given pitch or frequency, during the given time? For example, `play(440, 4)` should play the note A during 4 seconds.

I've found some libraries that can do what I said, but they don't play the music directly: you have to create a `.wav` file and, then, play this file. If I don't find any library that does what I want, I'll create a file, play it, and remove it for each note, but I think it would be more easy to do it directly.

Comment: take a look at various libaries at: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/.

maybe pyaudio?
http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Comment: @Raphael pyaudio can play .wav files but can not directly play the sound.

Answer (score 1):

---

I've finally found an answer to my question.

There's a module called `winsound` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html) which can play a sound of a given frequency and duration: `winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)`. But the problem is that it isn't cross-platform, only works for Windows operating systems.

So I've found another module called `pyaudiere` (https://pypi.org/project/pyaudiere/) which is cross-platform. It works a bit different than `winsound`. First you create a device: `d = audiere.open_device()`. Then, you can create a tone doing `t = d.create_tone(440)`. To play the tone you do `t.play()` and to stop it `t.stop()`. If you want to play it during some seconds you can use the `time` module. I'm still investigating but I think it only works for Python2. This is the stackoverflow post where I found the answer: [Python library for playing fixed-frequency sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974071/python-library-for-playing-fixed-frequency-sound).