# How to play stereo sound with PortAudio in C or PyAudio in Python

Tags: python, c++, c, linux, audio

I'm on a project with a mini PC (`Raspberry Pi` or `NVIDIA Jetson`).

I try to make play a sound and make a sound with a certain frequency stereo (left and right difference frequency/pitch and volume) and can change according to some conditions.

After my off-topic post, I learned from my mistake and tried `PortAudio` and `PyAudio` library. Looks like `PyAudio` is `PortAudio` Python Bindings, so I thought I could use both in my project since I'm working in `c++` and `python`.

However, I still confused how to make a two different sound (left and right) with different frequency. Here the code I used from [Python library for playing fixed-frequency sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974071/python-library-for-playing-fixed-frequency-sound)

```
from __future__ import division
import math

from pyaudio import PyAudio # sudo apt-get install python{,3}-pyaudio

try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError: # Python 3
    izip = zip
    xrange = range

def sine_tone(frequency, duration, volume=1, sample_rate=22050):
    n_samples = int(sample_rate * duration)
    restframes = n_samples % sample_rate

    p = PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(1), # 8bit
                    channels=1, # mono
                    rate=sample_rate,
                    output=True)
    s = lambda t: volume * math.sin(2 * math.pi * frequency * t / sample_rate)
    samples = (int(s(t) * 0x7f + 0x80) for t in xrange(n_samples))
    for buf in izip(*[samples]*sample_rate): # write several samples at a time
        stream.write(bytes(bytearray(buf)))

    # fill remainder of frameset with silence
    stream.write(b'\x80' * restframes)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

sine_tone(
    # see http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html
    frequency=440.00, # Hz, waves per second A4
    duration=3.21, # seconds to play sound
    volume=.01, # 0..1 how loud it is
    # see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate#Audio
    sample_rate=22050 # number of samples per second
)
```

I changed the channels to 2 and got the frequency 2x higher than 440Hz. So how to make it same 440Hz or different frequency between left and right?

Also I compared it with example code from `PortAudio`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "portaudio.h"

#define NUM_SECONDS   (2)
#define SAMPLE_RATE   (44100)
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER  (64)

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI  (3.14159265)
#endif

#define TABLE_SIZE   (300)
typedef struct
{
    float sine[TABLE_SIZE];
    int left_phase;
    int right_phase;
    char message[20];
}
paTestData;

/* This routine will be called by the PortAudio engine when audio is needed.
** It may called at interrupt level on some machines so don't do anything
** that could mess up the system like calling malloc() or free().
*/
static int patestCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                            unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                            const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                            PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                            void *userData )
{
    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData;
    float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;
    unsigned long i;

    (void) timeInfo; /* Prevent unused variable warnings. */
    (void) statusFlags;
    (void) inputBuffer;

    for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
    {
        *out++ = data->sine[data->left_phase];  /* left */
        *out++ = data->sine[data->right_phase];  /* right */
        data->left_phase += 1;
        if( data->left_phase >= TABLE_SIZE ) data->left_phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
        data->right_phase += 3; /* higher pitch so we can distinguish left and right. */
        if( data->right_phase >= TABLE_SIZE ) data->right_phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
    }

    return paContinue;
}

/*
 * This routine is called by portaudio when playback is done.
 */
static void StreamFinished( void* userData )
{
   paTestData *data = (paTestData *) userData;
   printf( "Stream Completed: %s\n", data->message );
}

/*******************************************************************/
int main(void);
int main(void)
{
    PaStreamParameters outputParameters;
    PaStream *stream;
    PaError err;
    paTestData data;
    int i;

    printf("PortAudio Test: output sine wave. SR = %d, BufSize = %d\n", SAMPLE_RATE, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);

    /* initialise sinusoidal wavetable */
    for( i=0; i<TABLE_SIZE; i++ )
    {
        data.sine[i] = (float) sin( ((double)i/(double)TABLE_SIZE) * M_PI * 2. );
    }
    data.left_phase = data.right_phase = 0;

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    outputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice(); /* default output device */
    if (outputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
      fprintf(stderr,"Error: No default output device.\n");
      goto error;
    }
    outputParameters.channelCount = 2;       /* stereo output */
    outputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32; /* 32 bit floating point output */
    outputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( outputParameters.device )->defaultLowOutputLatency;
    outputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &stream,
              NULL, /* no input */
              &outputParameters,
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff,      /* we won't output out of range samples so don't bother clipping them */
              patestCallback,
              &data );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    sprintf( data.message, "No Message" );
    err = Pa_SetStreamFinishedCallback( stream, &StreamFinished );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    err = Pa_StartStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    printf("Play for %d seconds.\n", NUM_SECONDS );
    Pa_Sleep( NUM_SECONDS * 1000 );

    err = Pa_StopStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );
    if( err != paNoError ) goto error;

    Pa_Terminate();
    printf("Test finished.\n");

    return err;
error:
    Pa_Terminate();
    fprintf( stderr, "An error occured while using the portaudio stream\n" );
    fprintf( stderr, "Error number: %d\n", err );
    fprintf( stderr, "Error message: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText( err ) );
    return err;
}
```

and I got more clean sound with C (PortAudio) than with Python (PyAudio). Any idea why? And I also didn't know why `TABLE_SIZE (300)` made 440Hz. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "I got more clean sound in 440Hz. Any idea why?" AFAIK, Raspberry PI has a pretty pure soundcard. So it may be hardware-related stuff

Comment: @P.Dmitry with same Raspberry Pi, the sound produced by C code (PortAudio) and Python (PyAudio) are difference. With Python, sound produced has a little noise like very high harmonics frequency. I don't know why, but since I used the same hardware, maybe there is something with the code.

Comment: @P.Dmitry I'm sorry I edited my question about it.