# ModuleNotFoundError at /admin No module named 'winsound'

Tags: django, pip, requirements.txt, winsound

I am developing an app in Django.

My app plays a sound using `winsound` module.

```
import sys
import winsound

duration = 150  # milliseconds
    freq = 440  # Hz
    winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
    winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
    winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
```

It worked fine as soon as I was developing in local, but when I pushed the app to heroku and then tryed to access the admin section, the web returned the error

> ModuleNotFoundError at /admin
>
> No module named 'winsound'

So I tryed to `pip install windsound` , but apparently there is no module having such name available for download.

Thinking that the module was maybe already installed but with another name, I also tried

```
pip freeze>requirements.txt
```

and added `'winsound'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, but nothing worked.

On the web I can find little information on winsound module and it appears it is not available to pip install with python... Does anybody knows how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try `pip3 install windsound`?

Comment: Yes, as for pip install winsound, it returns "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement winsound (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for winsound". Also note that the name of the module is "winsound" and not "winDsound".

Comment: The **actual** problem is that `winsound` is for Windows, and heroku is linux-based.

Comment: Thanks. I just got to it myself. write it as answer and I will flag as correct.

Comment: And what would be the point of playing a beep on Heroku anyway? Even if it worked, the beep would happen in Heroku's data centre somewhere, not on your machine.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. So how do I tell Django to play the sound in my user device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the operating system of heroku is linux, and `winsound` is **only** for Windows; So it won't be installed on heroku.