# Change the pitch (and speed) of audio during playback in Python

Tags: python, windows, audio, pitch

I'm working on a Python program that plays music. One feature will be a slider that the user can drag up or down to change the pitch of the music as it plays.

For example, if the pitch is set to 2, then the music will sound one octave higher, it will play twice as fast, and it will last half as long. All I'm really changing is the playback speed, but I need to do so interactively in real-time.

A good example of this functionality implemented in flash can be found [here](http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2009/pitch-mp3/). (It takes a little bit to load, be patient.)

I've looked into many python audio packages, but I haven't found one that can change the pitch of a sound that is currently playing. I have multiple versions of Python, so there is no requirement for what version the package supports. I'm developing this on Windows 7.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you want to resample the audio on-the-fly.

Perhaps you could try using the [scikits.samplerate](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.samplerate/) module. It uses the [Secret Rabbit Code library](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/).

Comment: The [only thing that scikits.samplerate does](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/samplerate/sphinx/fullapi.html) is to resample one numpy array into another. I understand that if I take a 44100 Hz sound, resample it to 22050 Hz, and then play it at 44100 Hz, it will be one octave higher. But now I need a way to play the sound and do the resampling on-the-fly, which is a big part of the original question.

Comment: I assumed you already knew how to implement basic playback of audio samples in Python.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me rephrase my statement. I need a method to play the sound that allows me to do the resampling on-the-fly. I'll check the python docs, but I'm not aware of any way to do this.

Comment: What module/framework are you currently using to play the audio?

Comment: So far I have been using the [Pygame mixer](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html), but I'd like to move away from it due major quality issues. I'm open to trying any suggested modules.

Comment: You would need an audio framework for streaming audio samples as a series of buffers of data. It looks as though PyGame's `pygame.mixer.music` doesn't give you that. How about [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org/). Or see [other SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python).

Answer (score 3):

With [Craig McQueen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982007/change-the-pitch-and-speed-of-audio-during-playback-in-python/3983095#3983095)'s help, I have created a proof-of-concept program.

This program plays a **mono** wav file called "music.wav" (located in the same folder as the program) and displays a short and wide window. The pitch of the music changes when you click and drag in the window. The left side of the window is two octaves lower, and the right side is two octaves higher.

There is some strange behavior here that I'm not sure how to fix. If the pitch is currently low, then there's about a 2 second delay before the pitch changes. However, the pitch changes in real-time for high pitches. (The delay increases smoothly as the pitch gets lower). I only add more sound to the buffer if `soundOutput.getLeft() < 0.2`. That is to say, if the amount of sound left on the buffer is less than 0.2 seconds. Therefore there should be no delay. For troubleshooting, I included code that writes `soundOutput.getLeft()` to a file. It tends to stay at or very near 0 all the time.

Decreasing the frames read to `waveRead.readframes(100)` decreases the delay, but also makes the sound choppy. Increasing the frames read significantly increases the delay.

```
import os, sys, wave, pygame, numpy, pymedia.audio.sound, scikits.samplerate

class Window:
    def __init__(self, width, height, minOctave, maxOctave):
        """
        width, height: the width and height of the screen.
        minOctave, maxOctave: the highest and lowest pitch changes. 0 is no change.
        """
        self.minOctave = minOctave
        self.maxOctave = maxOctave
        self.width = width
        self.mouseDown = False
        self.ratio = 1.0 # The resampling ratio
        waveRead = wave.open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "music.wav"), 'rb')
        sampleRate = waveRead.getframerate()
        channels = waveRead.getnchannels()
        soundFormat = pymedia.audio.sound.AFMT_S16_LE
        soundOutput = pymedia.audio.sound.Output(sampleRate, channels, soundFormat)
        pygame.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 0)
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        pygame.display.flip()
        fout = open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "musicdata.txt"), 'w') # For troubleshooting
        byteString = waveRead.readframes(1000) # Read at most 1000 samples from the file.
        while len(byteString) != 0:
            self.handleEvent(pygame.event.poll()) # This does not wait for an event.
            fout.write(str(soundOutput.getLeft()) + "\n") # For troubleshooting
            if soundOutput.getLeft() < 0.2: # If there is less than 0.2 seconds left in the sound buffer.
                array = numpy.fromstring(byteString, dtype=numpy.int16)
                byteString = scikits.samplerate.resample(array, self.ratio, "sinc_fastest").astype(numpy.int16).tostring()
                soundOutput.play(byteString)
                byteString = waveRead.readframes(500) # Read at most 500 samples from the file.
        waveRead.close()
        return

    def handleEvent(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            self.mouseDown = True
            self.setRatio(event.pos)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            self.mouseDown = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and self.mouseDown:
            self.setRatio(event.pos)
        return None

    def setRatio(self, point):
        self.ratio = 2 ** -(self.minOctave + point[0] * (self.maxOctave - self.minOctave) / float(self.width))
        print(self.ratio)

def main():
    Window(768, 100, -2.0, 2.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It's a pain to try to get all the packages I use to work well together. I'm using [Python 2.6.6](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/), [PyGame 1.9.1 for python 2.6](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml), [NumPy 1.3.0 for python 2.6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/), [PyMedia 1.3.7.3 for python 2.6](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), and [scikits.samplerate 0.3.1 for python 2.6](http://pypi.python.org/simple/scikits.samplerate/). Note that scikits.samplerate conflicts with NumPy 1.4 or greater, and one of the packages (I forget which one) requires [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)

Comment: I cannot pip install pymedia. Seems like an old / outdated  package. Any fix for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at using [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) to [create a media player](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/20/wxpython-creating-a-simple-mp3-player/), and investigate the [`SetPlaybackRate()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.media.MediaCtrl-class.html#SetPlaybackRate) function. [wxWidget docs here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9/classwx_media_ctrl.html#0b7026f35d08af8ebf4ee6fe3ba448c2).

That `SetPlaybackRate()` function is not supported on all platforms, and I've not tried it myself to see whether it does exactly what you want, and how well it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

setup tools is required for  scikits.samplerate 0.3.1

if you dont do that you will keep getting an error ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Comment: Just an update, it is now throwing this error if you don't have setuptools installed and up to date:

>>> from scikits.samplerate import resample
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "scikits/samplerate/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _samplerate import resample, available_convertors, src_version_str, \
ImportError: No module named _samplerate