# How to play a vector in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, audio, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Playing a sound from a wave form stored in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707967/playing-a-sound-from-a-wave-form-stored-in-an-array)

I'm trying to generate a vector (or similar data structure) in Python that contains a sine wave and play it without recording anything to disk.

Sort of like the following MATLAB code:

```
t = 0:1/8000:1;              % Generate a 1 second vector at a sampling rate of 8000 Hz
wave = sin(2*pi*440*t);      % Store a 440 Hz sine wave
sound(wave, 8000);           % Play the waveform
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tell us what you tried to achieve your goal.

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code in your question. Do not reply to this comment. http://v.gd/whathaveyoutried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `map` function to create the waveform;

```
import math
t = range(8001)
wave = map(lambda x: math.sin(2 * math.pi * 440 * x), t)
```

For playing sounds, I'd suggest using [ossaudiodev](http://docs.python.org/library/ossaudiodev.html) or [winsound](http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html), depending on your platform.

You would probably have to scale the `wave` array to a bytearray or a suitable type of numpy array for it to be digestable for the audio devices.