# Playing a sound from data stored in a variable in Python

Tags: python, audio

I am using Python 2.7, win 7, 64bit and I need to play a sound data stored in a variable. Of course, there is a possibility to make a WAV file and play it, but is there any option to play that directly? Could you recommend a library, etc. etc.? 
Apparently, audiere is outdated by now (as presented in [Playing a sound from a wave form stored in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707967/playing-a-sound-from-a-wave-form-stored-in-an-array)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be looking for is pyAudio : 
http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/

See in the example how they are storing a wav file in a variable and then playing it.

Comment: After weeks of googling and trying from time to time this actually was the most helpful example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202355/how-to-play-a-fixed-frequency-sound-using-python .
The problem is now how to do that with more than 8-bits (thats the limitations of char function).