# python equivalent play function of mathematica

Tags: python, python-2.7

I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhvW8yZdE5A) and naturally I was excited to see if I could do it as was done in video but instead use python for it rather than mathematica (which I do not have). Is there any simple way to play/synthesize sound in python.

for e.g. I want to play

Comment: Certainly not as easily as you could in Mathematica. Mathematica is _built_ for exactly this kind of thing; Python isn't.

Comment: I have solved something similar recently. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569889/playing-a-sound-from-data-stored-in-a-variable-in-python