# How to make Python play sound?

Tags: python, sockets

I am working on a Python chat script, the client looks like this:

```
import sys
import util
import thread
import socket


class ClientSocket():


rbufsize = -1
wbufsize = 0


def __init__(self, address, nickname=''):
    if type(address) == type(()) and type(address[0]) == type('') and 
type(address[1])== type(1):
        pass
    else:
        print ('Address is of incorrect type. \n' +
              'Must be (serverHost (str), serverPort (int)).')
        sys.exit(1)

    if nickname:
        self.changeNick(nickname)
    else:
        self.changeNick(raw_input('Nickname: '))

    self.prompt_on = False
    self.address = address


def connect(self):
    self.connection=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.connection.connect(self.address)
    self.rfile = self.connection.makefile('rb', self.rbufsize)
    self.wfile = self.connection.makefile('wb', self.wbufsize)

    self.wfile.write('/nick ' + self.nickname + '\n')


def serve_forever(self):
    self.connect()

    thread.start_new_thread(self.acceptinput,())

    line = ""
    while line not in ('/exit','/quit', '/q'):
        self.prompt_on = True
        line = raw_input(self.prompt)
        self.prompt_on = False
        if line[:2] == '/n' or line[:5] == '/nick':
            self.changeNick(line.split(' ', 1)[1].strip())
        self.wfile.write(line + '\n')

    self.close()
    self.connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    self.connection.close()


def changeNick(self, newNick):
    self.nickname = newNick
    self.prompt = self.nickname+': '
    self.backspace = '\b' * len(self.prompt)


def acceptinput(self):
    while 1:
        data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
        if data:
            self.writedata(data)
            if 'Nickname successfully changed to' in data:
                self.changeNick(data.split('"')[1])


def writedata(self, data):
    if self.prompt_on:
        output = data if len(data) >= len(self.prompt) else data + ' '
(len(self.prompt) - len(data))
        sys.stdout.write(self.backspace + output + '\n' + self.prompt)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
        print data


def close(self):
    if not self.wfile.closed:
        self.wfile.flush()
    self.wfile.close()
    self.rfile.close()


def main():
serverHost = raw_input('Server IP/Hostname: ')
if not serverHost:
    serverHost = util.getIP()
else:
    serverHost = socket.gethostbyname(serverHost)

serverPort = input('Server Port: ')
address = (serverHost, serverPort)

client = ClientSocket(address)
print 'Connecting to server on %s:%s' % (serverHost, serverPort)
client.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

I was wondering if there would be a way to play a sound every time a new messages. Possible using winsound ? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python)

Thanks:)

Comment: what does the socket program have to do with sound? try using small examples showing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am *pleasantly* surprised that [winsound](http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html) is standard library module. Just note that is only available on Windows.

What happens in your writa_data function you do this after the flush. Does this get your desired effect?

```
import winsound
# Play Windows exit sound.
winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

Comment: makes sense :) .. only, Ima new to Python, what line(s) would you place the `winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)` on?

Comment: Try it before/after - sys.stdout.flush()

Comment: Ah, I see where your talking about now. I tried it before and after `sys.stdout.flush()` and it wouldn't work and it closed it.

Comment: I see. I would try it as the last statement in write_data and to see if it's get called, I would do a `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` to go to debug and step through it.

Comment: okay.. I'm more of a noob to this than I thought... how do you do that..? I think you might have to fully explain this...

Comment: @SeanWebber - perhaps you may want to follow this - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfPtGsSJldg and look for how to do pdb

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out !!! Thanks for the help! :DDD

You add the `winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)` on line 101, above the `sys.stdout.write(self.backspace + output + '\n' + self.prompt)`. Now whenever a new message comes through, it plays a 'ding!'. If you wanted to use a custom .wav sound from the same directory the script is running from, add a `winsound.PlaySound("ding.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)` on line #101 instead. Enjoy!