# How to play music through Python with mpg321?

Tags: python

I want to play a music file with `mpg321` using Python using another event as the trigger. Then, when I type in a specific string, I'd like the music to stop playing.

How can I do this using Python?

Comment: let us know what you've tried

Comment: I've used 'os.popen(mpg321 /home/pi/voltage.mp3' under an if statement.

Comment: @user2340615 Note: With my alternatives for instance Pygame you can intercept key-presses and cause it to play/stop/pause music with a graphical front-end as well. The sky is the limit. The pyglet alternative is also nice.

Answer (score 10):

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
music = None
while 1:
    cmd = raw_input('> ')
    if cmd.lower() == 'play':
        music = Popen('mpg321 /home/Torxed/test.mp3'.split(' ',1), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    elif cmd.lower() == 'stop':
        try:
            music.stdout.close()
            music.stdin.close()
        except:
            pass
        music = None
```

Instead of using subprocess you could do:

```
music = os.popen('mpg321 /home/Torxed/test.mp3', 'w')
```

and just do

```
music.close()
```

I still think this is a horrible solution, because you shouldn't rely on out-side sources to do your task if you're a programmer.. it should be handled within your application and not so much on the os or some 3:d party application.

## Alternatives

**Pygame**: Go with for instance Pygame, it will do the job for you and then some.

```
import pygame, time
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/Torxed/test.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(5)
pygame.mixer.music.fadeout(5)
```

- More on this: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html

**The Snack Sound Toolkit**: It's a pure Python audio library with great flexibility!

```
s = Sound() 
s.read('/home/Torxed/test.mp3') 
s.play()
```

- More on this here: http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/

**Pyglet**: Easily my favorite, a cross-platform graphic OpenGL library with access to music as well:

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.resource.media('/home/Torxed/test.mp3')
music.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

- More on this here: http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/playing_sounds_and_music.html

## Python native alternatives

**Winsound** Is a Windows only alternative

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('C:\\users\\Torxed\\Desktop\\test.mp3')
```

**OSSaudio** This is a native Linux alternative to the others, OSS is one of the most default audio playbacks on Linux/Unix systems so it shouldn't be a strange option for most of the people out there. (Courtesy of @orestis here on Stackoverflow)

```
from wave import open as waveOpen
from ossaudiodev import open as ossOpen
s = waveOpen('/home/Torxed/test.wav','rb')
(nc,sw,fr,nf,comptype, compname) = s.getparams( )
dsp = ossOpen('/dev/dsp','w')
try:
  from ossaudiodev import AFMT_S16_NE
except ImportError:
  if byteorder == "little":
    AFMT_S16_NE = ossaudiodev.AFMT_S16_LE
  else:
    AFMT_S16_NE = ossaudiodev.AFMT_S16_BE
dsp.setparameters(AFMT_S16_NE, nc, fr)
data = s.readframes(nf)
s.close()
dsp.write(data)
dsp.close()
```

Some googling which led me to the OSS solution gave me this (be sure to credit those guys, good examples): [Play a Sound with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python)

Comment: great answer very helpful!