# notify when execution/command is completed

Tags: ipython, anaconda

How do I get IPython to notify me when a command has been executed? Can I get it to use the bell/alert, or by pop-up? I'm running Anaconda on iTerm on OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: Do you want this to happen automatically with every command, or only when you type some `notify_me()` at the end of the command?

Comment: You should change the accepted answer for the most voted since it was more useful for most of the people. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newest version of iTerm, you can use the alert on next mark functionality of the [shell integration](http://iterm2.com/shell_integration.html#/section/home).

Answer (score 31):

Finally someone [created a nice library for it](https://github.com/shoprunner/jupyter-notify).

You just install it:

```
pip install jupyternotify
```

Import it in your notebook:

```
import jupyternotify
ip = get_ipython()
ip.register_magics(jupyternotify.JupyterNotifyMagics)
```

and use a magic command:

```
%%notify
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

and get a nice notification:

[image]

Git-page also shows how to load it automatically.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically do this i.e. without having to explicitly call `%%notify` every time?

Comment: @RodrikTheReader, the same extension now supports `%autonotify -a 30` that notifies about each cell, that runs longer than 30 seconds

Comment: I'm getting "Javascript Error: $ is not defined"

Comment: This didn't seem to work with jupyterlab (the new version of jupyter that breaks everything). There is however https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab-notifications/  which looks like it works. But I think it needsd you to restart jupyter which I didn't want to do (since I was, perhaps unsurprisingly, waiting for a command to finished while I was installing this).

Answer (score 6):

Are you using IPython Notebook, or IPython from the terminal?  If you are using IPython Notebook, I suggest using the notify extension available from https://github.com/sjpfenninger/ipython-extensions (write up available [here](https://www.pfenninger.org/posts/ipython-notebook-extensions-to-ease-day-to-day-work/))

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted something for the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, I wrote a simple module/decorator function to notify on function completed (works only on MAC)

Example:

```
from ipynotifyer import notifyOnComplete as nf


@nf()
def divide_by_five():
    return 5/5

@nf(timer=True)
def divide_by_ten():
    return 5/10
```

https://github.com/Casyfill/ipython_notifier

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of iTerm send notifications to notification center when there is output in a non-visible tab. They fold into notification center by default, but you can change them to stay on the screen in the Notifications preferences in System Preferences.

Comment: That has never worked for me. Do you need to buy and install growl?

Comment: @Psquid see my other answer.