# Notification on Console output (Spyder)

Tags: machine-learning, console, spyder, coderunner

I use Spyder for training deep learning models , which usually take 10s of hours to get a result (Even with GPU setup).

I generally leave it overnight , but when I leave the program running during the day , is there a Spyder software hack , to get some sort of notification (email , sound(beep) , or pop up in Windows/Ubuntu) when the Console stops running and the output gets displayed.

(This will be very useful for me , as I can deploy another model , and reduce the waiting time.)

Comment: Please refer the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004386/notify-when-execution-command-is-completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no such functionality in Spyder, but it wouldn't be that hard to implement.

If you'd like to see this in a future release, please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues).