# How can i create sound alert when a cell in jupyter notebook finishes running?

Tags: audio, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to customize jupyter to play sound or some alert when it finishes running a cell?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. This is a little hack I use for most of my applications. It runs on Mac and Windows:

```
    def Beep(freq = 2100, duration = 300, repeat=3, sound_file=None):
    """Beep by FC:
       Funciona apenas Win e Mac
       freq     = 2100 (frequÃƒÂªncia)
       duration = 300  (duraÃƒÂ§ÃƒÂ£o em milissegundos)
       repeat   = 3    (nÃƒÂºmero de repetiÃƒÂ§ÃƒÂµes)
       sound_file = Submarine, Ping, Purr, Hero, Funk, Pop, Basso, Sosumi, Glass, Blow, Bottle, Frog, Tink, Morse
       (*) No Mac o ÃƒÂºnico parÃƒÂ¢metro vÃƒÂ¡lido ÃƒÂ© o nÃƒÂºmero de repetiÃƒÂ§ÃƒÂµes.
           A base para o "Beep" ÃƒÂ© o system/afplay
    """
    plataforma = str(platform.uname()).lower()
    if  not len ([s for s in ['windows','win32','win64'] if s in plataforma]) == 0:
        import winsound
        for i in range(repeat):
            winsound.Beep(freq,duration)
    elif not len ([s for s in ['darwin'] if s in plataforma]) == 0:
        import os
        for i in range(repeat):
            if sound_file is not None:
                if os.path.isfile(f"""/System/Library/Sounds/{sound_file}.aiff"""):
                    os.system(f"""afplay /System/Library/Sounds/{sound_file}.aiff""")
                else:
                    print(f"""/System/Library/Sounds/{sound_file}.aiff *NOT FOUND*""")
                    break
            else:
                os.system('afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Tink.aiff')
    else:
        print('Sorry, plataforma não identificada. Vc está usando Linux?')
    return
#Beep(sound_file='Hero', repeat=1)
```

Basically, if you are on Windows you have natively winsound. On Mac you have to play a sound manually, such as below:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('/path/to/note.wav') # .wav file
playsound('/path/to/note.mp3') # .mp3 file
```

However, I strongly suggest you use use **jupyternotify**, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004386/notify-when-execution-command-is-completed).