# play sound when Jupyter notebook cell fails

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Any trick to **play a sound whenever a Jupyter notebook cell throws an error**?

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17323336/125617), and I am currently using [cellbell](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cellbell/0.0.2) like this:

```
import cellbell

# line magic
%ding my_long_function()
```

but I don't know to make it run whenever one of my cells throws an error (except from wrapping every cell in try/catch clauses).

I guess what I would need is something like an "error-hook", similar to a [savehook](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/savehooks.html)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Without `cellbell`** (more generic answer)

Define a function in your notebook.  **Note: `Audio` must be passed to `display`

```py
from IPython.display import Audio, display

def play_sound(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset=None):
    self.showtraceback((etype, value, tb), tb_offset=tb_offset)
    display(Audio(url='http://www.wav-sounds.com/movie/austinpowers.wav', autoplay=True))
```

set a custom exception handler, you can list exception types in the tuple.

```py
get_ipython().set_custom_exc((ZeroDivisionError,), play_sound)
```

test it:

```py
1/0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-05c9758a9c21> in <module>()
----> 1 1/0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

**With `cellbell`**:
The difference is using the `%ding` magic.

```py
import cellbell

def play_sound(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset=None):
    %ding
    self.showtraceback((etype, value, tb), tb_offset=tb_offset)
    print('ding worked!')
```

reset the custom exeception, note you can use `Exception` to play a sound on any error:

```py
get_ipython().set_custom_exc((Exception,), play_sound)
```

test:

```py
1/0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-05c9758a9c21> in <module>()
----> 1 1/0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

ding worked!
```

tested on jupyter notebook 4.2.3