# How do I make my jupyter notebooks beep/alarm me if any cell throws error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I run my notebook in the background for they take forever to run, and what I want is, if any cell throws error, I'd want the notebook to beep
One method is to use try/except

```
try:
  //run my code
except:
   // beep
```

Now this isn't something one would like to write in every cell of the notebook, what would be a possible way that jupyter notebook would do it on its own

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603739/16349299

Comment: Does this answer your question? [play sound when Jupyter notebook cell fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722417/play-sound-when-jupyter-notebook-cell-fails)