# Playing multiple sounds in one Jupyter Notebook cell

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The question is similar to [Automatically play sound in IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323336/automatically-play-sound-in-ipython-notebook) - the diffrence is I need to play the sound several times. At the browser side - not the server.

The most naive approach:

```
IPython.display.Audio(url="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg", autoplay=True)
time.sleep(10)
IPython.display.Audio(url="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg", autoplay=True)
```

does not work as it plays the sound once. Moreover, it seems that it is necessary for `IPython.display.Audio` object to be the output of the cell, as:

```
IPython.display.Audio(url="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg", autoplay=True)
None
```

plays no sound.

Splitting the code into several cells is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out (and cleaned my code a bit):

```
horse = IPython.display.Audio(url="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg",
                              autoplay=True)
IPython.display.display(horse)
time.sleep(10)
IPython.display.display(horse)
```