# Automatic cell execution timing in jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

In jupyter **notebook**, I can configure an automatic cell timing with [nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions), the result is like so:

[image: jupyter_notebook]

How can I do this in jupyter **lab**? I didn't find any extensions that do a similar thing.

Obs.: I know that a similar result can be achieved with `%%time` magic, but I want it to be automatic, so I don't have to place the magic function at the beginning of each cell.

Comment: If you don't mind to code it on your own, you could use post and pre excute hooks, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50648266/6646912

Comment: Official thread: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3320 Does this help?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## Requirement

> JupyterLab >= 2.0.2

[image]

Let's move step by step

## Extension available for JupyterLab is

> jupyterlab-execute-time

First enable Extension Manager

[image]

After enabling you see new button in side task bar at the end "Extension Manager"

You can also enable it with the following steps:

1. Go into advanced settings editor.
2. Open the Extension Manager section.
3. Add the entry “enabled”: true.
4. Save the settings.
   If prompted whether you are sure, read the warning, and click “Enable” if you are still sure.
   Once enabled, you should see a new tab appear in the left sidebar
   [image]

By default, the disclaimer is not acknowledged.
[image]

As the disclaimer is not acknowledged, you can search for an extension, but can not install it (no install button is available).
[image]

To install an extension, you first have to explicitly acknowledge the disclaimer. Once done, this will remain across sessions and the user would not have to check it again.

[image]

## Finding Extension

[image]

search jupyterlab-execute-time

> Install
> Enable

After enable you have to Rebuild it: A small popup window open on it click on Rebulid;

then you have to restart kernel

Still you find you will not able to see what you want :

## Last thing

Note: for this to show anything, you need to enable cell timing in the notebook via Settings->Advanced Settings Editor->Notebook: {"recordTiming": true}

## Advanced Settings Editor

[image]

finally "recordTiming"=true

[image]

and save it at right end!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed explanation.
I'm getting the error:
```
An error occurred installing <code>jupyterlab-execute-time</code>.

Error message:

The extension "jupyterlab-execute-time" does not yet support the current version of JupyterLab.


Conflicting Dependencies:
JupyterLab                  Extension      Package
>=3.0.4 <3.1.0              >=2.0.2 <3.0.0 @jupyterlab/application
>=3.0.4 <3.1.0              >=2.0.2 <3.0.0 @jupyterlab/notebook
>=3.0.2 <3.1.0              >=2.0.1 <3.0.0 @jupyterlab/settingregistry
```

any idea what I can do?

Comment: @LeonidGaneline it is not working for your jupyter-lab version. It supports <3.0.0 so you can use with downgraded jupyter-lab. I hope they fix.

Comment: As of 4/2/21, this is working for JupyterLab v3.0.12.

Comment: In my case, the last step: refresh the browser, so the jupyterlab can rebuild and show the timing message.

Comment: I get the same kind of error (12/7/21) as Leonid did on v3.0.14. It lists the dependencies as >= 3.0.9 and >=3.0.5, though, so I don't understand how this was working for Jadon's v3.012.

Comment: It would be great to be able to add the `{"recordTiming": true}` line from the terminal directly instead of from the GUI

Comment: won't work for jupyter-lab > 3.2.
Extension Installation Error
An error occurred installing <code>jupyterlab-execute-time</code>.

Error message:

The extension "jupyterlab-execute-time" does not yet support the current version of JupyterLab.


Conflicting Dependencies:
JupyterLab                  Extension      Package
>=3.2.1 <3.3.0              >=2.0.2 <3.0.0 @jupyterlab/application
>=3.2.1 <3.3.0              >=2.0.2 <3.0.0 @jupyterlab/notebook
>=3.2.1 <3.3.0              >=2.0.1 <3.0.0 @jupyterlab/settingregistry

Comment: For people getting the error message regarding noje js installation missing, try installing the execute-time via pip , it worked for me. >>pip install jupyterlab_execute_time

Comment: Answer is very verbose, at least it should mention the jupyterlab-execute-time extension name in the beginning.

Comment: Also answer is outdated since jupyterlab 3.0 was released more than 2 years ago.

Answer (score 32):

Appreciated the answer of @welcome_back, but you don't have to mess with the jupyter extension manager especially if you are concerned about that warnings.

#### Enable execution time in 3 steps

- install this package
  `!pip install jupyterlab_execute_time`
- reload the jupyterlab page (no need to shut down)
- go to notebook section in jupyterlab advanced setting and paste this code

```
{"recordTiming": true}
```

###### And voila!! you are done!

Comment: Works for me, just to add that, the last step is added in the json view of the setting page, not the GUI page.

Comment: This legit works. For the last step, you can also enable it from GUI by going to ```Advance Settings Editor``` > `Execute Time`, then check the `Enabled` checkbox.

Answer (score 18):

No need for an extension.

Simply use (at any cell):

```
try:
    %load_ext autotime
except:
    !pip install ipython-autotime
    %load_ext autotime
```

To stop cell timing, use:

```
%unload_ext autotime
```

Comment: it's great. In 2022, it workes for jupyter lab >= 3.2.0

Comment: Does one have to do this each time they open JupyterLab?

Answer (score 5):

When trying to install for jypyter lab >= 3.0.0 use:

`pip install jupyterlab_execute_time`