# jupyterlab-execute-time although installed does not function in the notebok with jupyterlab 2.2.0a0

Tags: python-3.x, extension-methods, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I have installed jupterlab version 2.2.0a0 and the extension jupyterlab-execute-time.

[image]

[image]

However when I run a cell the execution time is not reported:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: You're not alone... happens to me too. I'm running it in Conda, on macOS Catalina. — As I side note, while I was installing the extension my computer crashed, it could be that it made it crash or maybe the crash broke it, I also had a Firefox update pending, which I've seen makes stuff unstable, not sure why.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843745/automatic-cell-execution-timing-in-jupyter-lab/61159513#61159513. Most likely the record timing flag is not set.

Answer (score 2):

Following the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61159513/12771385)

> You need to enable cell timing in the notebook via Settings->Advanced
> Settings Editor->Notebook: {"recordTiming": true}

After this, it should work properly.

Comment: I don't see "Notebook" section in my Advanced Settings Editor. There is "Notebook Panel" instead. Note that I have the following:  
> 1. JupyterLab v3.6.3  
> 2. jupyterlab_execute_time v3.0.0  
> 3. Python 3.10