# Jupyter / Python — Is there a way to run magic commands like %%time automatically in each Jupyter cell?

Tags: python, time, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm writing a jupyter notebook where more often than not I want to be able to quickly reference wall time for every cell. Is there a way to set jupyter up so that `%%time` runs automatically in every cell without typing it in each time?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245170/how-to-enable-timing-magics-for-every-cell-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: For the very specific use case of %%time in JupyterLab see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61159513/6646912

Comment: For pre- and post-execution hooks in IPython see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323336/automatically-play-sound-in-ipython-notebook/50648266#50648266

Comment: Thanks; these resources solved the issue. I'm not seeing them come up when I google relevant terms for SO or through SO's search, so I'm going to leave this up in case it helps direct searches to these posts.