# Playing mp3 files using python 2.7 buttons - TKinter

Tags: python-2.7, button, audio, tkinter

Hello I am trying to create a button that plays a mp3 file using TKinter so far I have the following code. I cant get it to play the mp3 file

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import winsound

    app = Frame(root)
    app.pack(side='bottom')
    button1 = Button(app, text="Enter Program", command=winsound.PlaySound('music.mp3',winsound.SND_FILENAME))
    button1.pack()
```

Thanks

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: i cant get it to play the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pyglet library to play mp3 files but you should also have installed `avbin` library. (https://code.google.com/p/avbin/)

Another problem is, tkinter has its own main loop and pyglet has its own. So you should use threads. This code might give you an idea:

```
from Tkinter import *

from threading import Thread
import pyglet

root = Tk()
app = Frame(root)
app.pack(side='bottom')

player = pyglet.media.Player()
music_file = pyglet.media.load('foo.mp3')

def startPlaying():
    player.queue(music_file)
    player.play()
    pyglet.app.run()

def playSound():
    global sound_thread 
    sound_thread = Thread(target=startPlaying)
    sound_thread.start()

button1 = Button(app, text="Enter Program", command=playSound)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
pyglet.app.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes there:

1. The classic `command` error: When you pass an argument like this:

   ```
   Button(..., command=winsound.PlaySound(...))
   ```

   you're *calling* `PlaySound` and use its return value (which defaults to `None`), so you're passing `command=None`. Use `lambda`:

   ```
   Button(..., command=lambda: winsound.PlaySound(...))
   ```
2. `winsound` is not made to play `mp3`s, but `wav`s. Use another library, suggestions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python).