# Python - winsound and SND not working

Tags: winsound

Hi i am having a few problems with the winsound i want to play a short sound clip and on this page here: [Play a Sound with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python) it is said that this should work:

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

on mine i get the error, the program and the audio file which is a .wav are both in the same folder, and im not sure why any help? 
Code:

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_audio)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\----\----\python\test\soundtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_audio)
AttributeError: module 'winsound' has no attribute 'SND_audio'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace .SND_audio with .SND_FILENAME as it said on the page and it should work.

If it still doesn't work try .SND_ASYNC

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Code required to get it running was adding

```
winsound.PlaySound("soundname.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```