# I tried to run a simple gTTS speech message but while the mp3 file is being made, i cant hear anything when i try to run it

Tags: python, gtts

I am using Sublime Text 3 and Python 3.7.6.

Here is the code I'm using;

```
from gtts import gTTS
tts = gTTS(text="Hello crazy programmer", lang='en')
tts.save("audio.mp3")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run it" here? The code looks like it's creating an `mp3` file, so I would expect that the result of running this would be that an `mp3` would fall out of the program. Are you trying to play the resulting MP3 and it's silent?

Comment: Why is this tagged as a Sublime Text question? Because it's on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

The above code just create a mp3 file, you have to use a mp3 player to play it.
I would suggest using playsound library for simplicity but you can find more options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python)

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound("audio.mp3")
```

If this is not the case, you may check if GTTS save the mp3 file correctly by double-clicking in and play with your built-in mp3 player.
For more safety, I suggest using something like this instead of your code:

```
        try:
            tts = gTTS(text=self.__speech, lang=self.__lang)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to generate speech from text")
            removeSpeech()
            exit(e)
        else: #if no exception then save the file
            tts.save(self.__name_save)
```

Comment: Would not recommend using exit inside the exception block, just `raise` the error if you don't want to ignore it.