# Looking for a way to play sound while using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, tkinter

I've gone through all the solutions I found online, and none of them really worked. Most weren't supported by my os and/or by my python version which is 3. Only one which actually played was pygame. But pygame didn't work with tkinter. I'm using an android device, so winsound can't be used.

Comment: Did you got an error?

Comment: I think `threading` or `multiprocessesing` is what you need

Comment: tkinter has no features for playing sounds other than a system beep.

Comment: Being myself new to python, I recently switched from tkinter to Qt (you can use PyQt for PySide). It has a bit of a steeper learning curve than tkinter but is well worth it for the plugins and ability to customise. It has capability to play sounds https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtMultimedia/QSound.html and a nice designer (Qt designer) for desinging GUIs).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play a Sound with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python). Read also: [use threads to preventing main event loop from “freezing”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747734/7414759)

Comment: the threading thing will probably work, but honestly it's above my level right now. I'll start learning it. And PyQt seems to be unnecessarily complicated, although it's design features are interesting. I've probably just been spoiled by tkinter though.