# Cross Platform Python Sound Library for Linux, Windows, and Mac OS

Tags: python, audio

I am developing a little sound player in python (wxPython) which I would like to use on Linux, Windows, and OSX.  Looking for a sound library that I can use cross platform.  Ideally one that has support for most of the major codecs (or uses what is installed on the user's system).  Fading between files would be a plus, however not a necessity.  No manipulation of the actual audio files is needed- just a way to play them from within Python.

Comment: Also note that said duplicatee is itself marked a possible duplicate of [Play audio with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python) and [What's a cross platform way to play a sound file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276266/whats-a-cross-platform-way-to-play-a-sound-file-in-python), and there are dozens more under the Related links.

Comment: Answer at Play a sound with Python recommends Snack (http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/), which, as of this writing, supports WAV, AU, AIFF, MP3, CSL, SD, SMP, and NIST/Sphere, and is cross-platform.

Comment: @JasonC, the Snack library hasn't been updated since 2004.

Comment: If it works, it may not have needed an update. :-) There is a more complete list of options at http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/ (see platform-independent section).