# Method for playing a sound file in pyaudio at Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyaudio, ioerror

I attempted to play a.wav file with pyaudio. It works fine in Windows, but not in Ubuntu when another device is using sound.

and got this error:

```
IOError: [Errorno Invalid output device (no default output device)] -9996
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **wxPython**
as example:

```
sound.Play(wx.SOUND_ASYNC)
```

and sound variable can be defined like this:

```
sound = wx.Sound('sound.wav')
```

you can see this question as reference seems you have the same problem.
[What's a cross platform way to play a sound file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276266/whats-a-cross-platform-way-to-play-a-sound-file-in-python?rq=2)

Comment: If you have identified an exact duplicate, flag the question as duplicate instead of reproducing it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply use **simpleaudio**

```
import simpleaudio
wave_obj = simpleaudio.WaveObject.from_wave_file("sound.wav")
play_obj = wave_obj.play()
play_obj.wait_done()
```